# When to use the AngularJS `$onInit` Life-Cycle Hook

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-components, angularjs-1.7

With the release of AngularJS V1.7, the option to pre-assign bindings to has deprecated and removed:

> Due to [38f8c9](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/38f8c97af74649ce224b6dd45f433cc665acfbfb), **directive bindings are no longer available in the constructor**.
>
> To migrate your code:
>
> - If you specified `$compileProvider.preAssignBindingsEnabled(true)` you need to first migrate your code so that the flag can be flipped to `false`. The instructions on how to do that are available in the  ["Migrating from 1.5 to 1.6" guide](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/migration#migrate1.5to1.6-ng-services-$compile). Afterwards, remove the `$compileProvider.preAssignBindingsEnabled(true)` statement.
>
> — [AngularJS Developer Guide - Migrating to V1.7 - Compile](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/migration#-compile-)

> Due to [bcd0d4](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/bcd0d4d896d0dfdd988ff4f849c1d40366125858), pre-assigning bindings on controller instances is disabled by default.  **We strongly recommend migrating your applications to not rely on it as soon as possible.**
>
> Initialization logic that relies on bindings being present should be put in the controller's `$onInit()` method, which is guaranteed to always be called *after* the bindings have been assigned.
>
> — [AngularJS Developer Guide - Migrating from v1.5 to v1.6 - $compile](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/migration#migrate1.5to1.6-ng-services-$compile)

What are the use cases when code has to be moved to the [`$onInit` Life-Cycle Hook](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#life-cycle-hooks)? When can we just leave the code in the controller construction function?

Comment: If code does not use any bindings, you can leave it -- or you think there is something more deep here?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Code has to be moved in the `$onInit` function, when it depends on bindings, because these bindings are not available within `this` in the constructor. They get assigned AFTER instantiation of the component class.

Example:
You have a state definition like this:

```
$stateProvider.state("app", {
  url: "/",
  views: {
    "indexView": {
      component: "category"
    }
  },
  resolve: {
    myResolve: (someService) => {
      return someService.getData();
    }
  }
});
```

You can bind the result of `myResolve` to your component like this:

```
export const CategoryComponent = {
  bindings: {
    myResolve: "<"
  },
  controller: Category
};
```

If you now log out `this.myResolve` in the `constructor` and in `$onInit` you will see something like this:

```
constructor() {
  console.log(this.myResolve); // <-- undefined
}

$onInit() {
  console.log(this.myResolve); // <-- result of your resolve
}
```

So, your constructor should only contain constructing code like:

```
constructor() {
  this.myArray = [];
  this.myString = "";
}
```

Every angular specific initialisation and binding or dependency usage should be in `$onInit`

Comment: Trying to think of why I'd leave something in the constructor proper and not just go ahead and place everything in `$onInit()`. I understand you _could_ argue that's not as expressive as grouping non-binding-related code in the constructor, but that's the best reach I've got so far.

Comment: From an AngularJs point of view, you are totally right. $onInit is mostly sufficient. But keep in mind, that $onChanges runs before $onInit (in AngularJs 1.5.5 and above) and you might use uninitialized properties.
From an OOP point of view, initializing in the constructor is preferred.